# Serve zip file from AWS Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-serverless

I need an endpoint (serverless) that serves a series of files compressed in a zip file. To do this I am using [node-zip](https://github.com/daraosn/node-zip). This works locally to create a simple zip file with a flat file text:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const zip = new require('node-zip')()

const flat_text = 'This is a flat text file'

zip.file('a_file.txt', flat_text)
fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/a_file.zip', zip.generate({base64: false, compression: 'DEFLATE'}), 'binary')
```

But when I try to implement it in a lambda the downloaded zip file is corrupted:

```
module.exports.weekly = async (event, context) => {
    const flat_text = 'This is a flat text file'
    zip.file('a_file.txt', flat_text)
    return {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/zip, application/octet-stream',
            'Content-disposition': `attachment; filename=${`any_name_${new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10)}.zip`}`
        },
        body:  zip.generate({base64: false, compression: 'DEFLATE'}),
        statusCode: 200
    }
}
```

Why do I get a corrupted zip file?

## Update

What I did in the end to fix this:

- Change the body of the request to a base64 string (jszip: `generateAsync({type: 'base64'})`)
- Make the API Gateway serve binary content: https://medium.com/nextfaze/binary-responses-with-serverless-framework-and-api-gateway-5fde91376b76

Comment: Did you try adding `isBase64Encoded : true` in the response object?

Comment: @AtharKhan since the zip is not generated as a base64 string I didnt try that

Comment: @AtharKhan but I switched to base 64 when generating the zip and when sending the response and that worked. If you write it as a response I will mark it as correct. Thank you!

Comment: Added in the answer, thank you :)

Comment: How were you able to use `node-zip` on AWS lambda?

Comment: @onassar I no longer have access to that codebase but it was pretty straightforward, are you having problems with node-zip?

Comment: Ended up just going directly w/ `jszip` so it's fine. thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try encoding the response as Base64 encoded string by adding `isBase64Encoded: true` in the response object.

Answer (score 0):

The Easiest way to do it is by Zipping the file and putting in back in the same bucket and then getting SignedUrl for that file.